# get index of dropdown with the same class name

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown which is as follows:

```
<select class="form-control sn-item-reveived-ddl">
<option value>Have you received this item?></option>
<option value="True">Yes</option>
<option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

I have numerous dropdowns like above with the same class. What I am trying to do is get the index and the value of the select one. For that my jQuery code is as follows

```
$('.sn-item-reveived-ddl').change(function () {
   var value = $(this).val(); //this brings back the correct value of the dropdown
   var index = $('option:selected').index(); //if i use this it keeps returning index 0

    console.log(index);
});
```

Problem I am having is that I can get the correct value by using `this` keyword, however if I try to get the index it picks up the index of the first dropdown with the class named `sn-item-received-ddl`. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please.

Comment: try add a `$` to `('option:selected').index()` == `$('option:selected').index()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sorry, that was a typo, it's already in the code. I've updated the question too

Comment: Use this `var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();`

Comment: @John Quotes around `this` will not work as expected in this `$('this').find(...`

Comment: @Madhavan.V Have already edited it few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `this` to `$('option:selected')` so it looks like `$('option:selected', this)` Then it should work.

Then it will get the index of the selected option in the dropdown you just changed.

```js
$('.sn-item-reveived-ddl').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val(); //this brings back the correct value of the dropdown
  var index = $('option:selected', this).index(); //if i use this it keeps returning index 0

  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control sn-item-reveived-ddl">
<option value>Have you received this item?></option>
<option value="True">Yes</option>
<option value="False">No</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control sn-item-reveived-ddl">
<option value>Have you received this item?></option>
<option value="True">Yes</option>
<option value="False">No</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control sn-item-reveived-ddl">
<option value>Have you received this item?></option>
<option value="True">Yes</option>
<option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks, I will accept it as soon as the time limit is up

Comment: @Code No problem, happy to help